# if ["$i" -gt "$count"]; IS GIVING AN ERROR

Tags: shell

I'm trying to put the 'f-$count'(f-1,f-2) name into the array.

Below is the code,

```
echo "Enter the count"
read count
echo $count

#arr=()
i=1
while true;
do
 if ["$i" -gt "$count"]; then
  exit 0
 else
  arr[$i]=f-$i
  i=$((i+1))
 fi
done
echo ${arr[@]}
```

I'm getting the error as 'script.sh: line 11: [3570: command not found
' continuously.

Comment: This is covered in the BashPitfalls page: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: FYI, if you're using bash or another modern ksh derivative (which you obviously are, since your code uses arrays), the modern/preferred syntax for this comparison is `if (( i > count )); then`.

Answer (score 4):

In shell programming, the brackets in the `if` MUST be delimited by spaces:

```
if ["$i" -gt "$count"]; then
```

MUST be:

```
if [ "$i" -gt "$count" ]; then
```

**[EDIT]** The left bracket (`[`) is actually a built-in shell command and so requires the space afterwards to delimit it from its parameters, as with any command.

Comment: That's because `[` is actually a command, not mere syntax, and commands must be separated by their arguments by whitespace.

Comment: @glennjackman thanks for the comment/clarification. I've updated accordingly.

Comment: FYI, `[` is a builtin command on any modern shell -- so even though `/usr/bin/[` exists, that's not what's actually being used, so its invocation doesn't actually involve a fork/exec cycle. Run `type [` to see.